# Laravel iterate array and write to Model with Relations

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I think about dynamic model creation or updating an model.
Let's assume i have an array like this:

```
$data = array(
'first_name' => 'Max',
'last_name' => 'Power',
'invoiceAddress.city' => 'Berlin',
'invoiceAddress.country_code' => 'DE',
'user.status_code' => 'invited'
);
```

Now i would like to iterate that array, and write the data to an model, where the dot notation tells me that i must write to an relation.

Normal code:

```
$model->first_name = $data['first_name'];
$model->last_name = $data['last_name'];
$model->invoiceAddress->city = $data['invoiceAddress.city'];
```

and so on.

I would prefer a more dynamic way:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
  $properties = explode('.',$key);
  //Now the difficult part
  $model[$properties[0]][$properties[1]] = $value;
  //Would work for invoiceAddress.city,
  //but not for first_name
}
```

Here is the problem, that i don't know how many properties the explode will create.
Is there a way to solve such problem in a dynamic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Illuminate\Support\Arr` helper from Laravel like this:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    Arr::set($model, $key, $value);
}
```

It works because the `Arr` class uses dot notation to access the properties like:

```
Arr::get($model, 'invoiceAddress.country_code');
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$model['invoiceAddress']['country_code'];
```

If you prefer to use cleaner helper:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    array_set($model, $key, $value);
}
```

Comment: Sir, you are a genius!
It's working exactly the way i want. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use these Laravel helpers [data_fill()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-fill) or [data_set()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-set).

Other `doted notation` functions are listed [here](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Arr.html).